# Blank graph for some munin plugins

Tags: munin

I have a munin-master and munin-node installed on same server (Ubuntu 9.10 server).

Most pre-installed plugins work well but the following plugins are with blank graph:

```
Memcached bytes used
Memcached connections
Memcached cache hits and misses
Memcached cached items
Memcached requests
Memcached network traffic
MySQL Queries Cache Size
```

I run the following 3 script in terminal and results were ok.

```
/etc/munin/plugins/memcached_bytes
/etc/munin/plugins/memcached_counters
/etc/munin/plugins/memcached_rates
```

But when I tried the command below after "telnet localhost 4949"

```
fetch memcached_bytes 
# Unknown service
etch memcached_bytes_
# timeout pid 28009 - killing...done
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Can you post the output from:
munin-run memcached_bytes --debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you restart munin-node after putting the memcached plugins in the plugin directory? Are any of them listed if you run 'list' when connected with telnet?

Any of the memcached plugins I've seen need the port and ip included in the name of the plugin, like the if_ scripts, where there's just symlinks into /etc/munin/plugins like:

```
# ls /etc/munin/plugins/memcached_bytes_127_0_0_1_11211 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 2010-02-01 05:56 /etc/munin/plugins/memcached_bytes_127_0_0_1_11211 -> /usr/local/share/munin/memcached_bytes_
```

Comment: @theothererreceive, munin-node had been restarted I even run "sudo -u munin munin-cron" but no luck. Looks like there is no need to put host and port into memcached plugins link according to the installation guide come with the script.

Comment: @theothererreceive, the plugin i used is from http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/trunk/plugins/node.d/memcached_.in

Comment: I used a link like
11211_memcached_new_bytes -> /usr/share/munin/plugins/memcached_new_

and then configured separate port configs in the plugin-conf.d. I *wish* I could make the magic linking as described here work. It would be much more elegant.